# Is it necessary to put a website in the play console account information?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have noticed that if I go to "Account information" I have marked "website" as "I don´t have any website" and the following message is displayed:

**By adding a website, you help us verify your account. If you don't have a website yet, use a social media profile.**

My question is, if my account is already verified because I have uploaded many apps, why that message is shown? Will it be better to add a website to let google verify my account better and have more installs in my apps or it is absolutely irrelevant and not important if I don´t add any website in "Account information"? Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't affect your account in terms of installs and stuff, but doesn't harm to add a link as well. You could either use a social link or a free site via Firebase Hosting.

Comment: @DarShan thanks, but I don´t undesratnd really well why it is warned "you help us verify your account", so if my account is now verified as I have upload many apps,  could I have problems in the future if I don´t add a web page like being unverifyed or banned?  Also could I add my incomplete blogger website without absoulutely anything of text(just a title), or it should be a more official page like .com?